# PUT request won't updated data | React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

In my database, I have an object called `lock`. Currently, you can (almost, I broke it somehow) update the locks settings with my axios put request. But in the `lock` object there's a key called `controller` which has an objectId. I also have another object called `controller` which contains stuff that I need to be able to updated also (from the same put request).

I've made sure that I am matching the correct `lock` with the correct `controller`, but I can't seem to get my put request to work.

In my React app I have this (`item = lock | I need to rename it`):

```
<DoorSettingsForm
  onSubmit={updateSettings}
  item={location.state.door}
  id={location.state.door._id}
  controller={location.state.controller}
/>
```

The `DoorSettingsForm` component takes in three props, one if which are a function, `updateSettings`. In the same folder I have this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateSettings: (id, item, controller) =>
      dispatch(updateSettings(id, item, controller))
  }
}
```

And my action:

```
export function updateSettings(id, updatedValues) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    let item
    state.fetchDoors.doors.forEach(val => {
      if (val._id === id) item = val
    })
    const payload = { item: merge({}, item, updatedValues) }
    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, payload.item)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('updatedValues', updatedValues)
        dispatch({
          type: 'SETTINGS_UPDATED',
          payload
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Right now when I try to send this request I only get the `id` of the lock, but not the other values I want. When I `console.log('updatedValues', updatedValues)` I can see all the values that I've changed. So I wonder what's wrong with my actions?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: what is your exactly problem? the payload.item doesn't get send in axios.put?

Comment: `I only get the id of the lock`. Where is this? In the Redux state? Have you console.log:ed `payload` to see that it contains what you think? If the issue is that the new values aren't reflected in the Redux state (and the payload looks like it should), then I would have to see the reducer for the `SETTINGS_UPDATED` action.